# Foundation Reveal Modal not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation in an ember app and trying to make my log in/ sign up form a reveal modal.  I found a building blocks tutorial on foundation's website for how to do this, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the template code:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="LogInModal" class="button">Launch Signup Modal</a>

<div id="LogInModal" class="reveal-modal remove-whitespace" data-reveal>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns auth-plain">
      <div class="signup-panel left-solid">
        <p class="welcome">Registered Users</p>
        <form>
          <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-2  columns">
              <span class="prefix"><i class="fi-torso-female"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-10  columns">
              <input type="text" placeholder="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-2 columns ">
              <span class="prefix"><i class="fi-lock"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-10 columns ">
              <input type="text" placeholder="password">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <a href="#" class="button ">Log In </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-6 columns auth-plain">
      <div class="signup-panel newusers">
        <p class="welcome"> New User?</p>
        <a href="#" class="button ">Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>

   </div>   
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the necessary custom styling:

```
/* Styles for signup panels */
.auth-plain {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.left-solid {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.signup-panel {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}

.signup-panel a{
  color: #fff;
}

.signup-panel i {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #999;
}
.signup-panel form input, .signup-panel form span {
  height: 50px;
}
.signup-panel .welcome {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.signup-panel p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
.signup-panel .button {
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.newusers {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the Foundation javascript files? And calling `$(document).foundation();`?

Comment: Where do I call the `$(document).foundation();`? @BrettDeWoody

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the Foundation plugins on your page by adding:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

just before the closing `</body>` tag. More info in the [Foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html).

Comment: Just did that and still not showing up.  I also think I am loading the javascript files.  Do you think there is anything else I have to be doing because it is an ember app?

Comment: Are you including `foundation.min.js` or the individual plugin `.js` files in your page? Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I've included the entire `foundation.js` in my ember-cli-build.js file.  I do get this error in my browser console when I click the open modal button: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (foundation-icons.css, line 0) @BrettDeWoody

Comment: Have you looked into Ember modals - http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: Oh I have not. I'll look into those now. @BrettDeWoody